# PHP: uri rewrite (WITH sub-domains) on a single page website (index.php) to process ALL pages and URL's based on MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, url-rewriting, single-page-application

I am building a website from scratch. EVERYTHING is in MySQL, all the code, meta data, js codes, CSS, body content, EVERYTHING. For that purpose, I created a class that renders an HTML page, based on variables provided by domain.com/index.php.

I got insipid to do it this way, based on a blog I found a while back. It came with a full tutorial. Unfortunately, I can't find it anymore.

Anyway, my "master" table, `URL's` is configured like so:

```
| subdomain      | category   | subcategory | page        | extension |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                | properties | houses      | downtown-la | html      |
| properties     | houses     | downtown    |             | /         |
| ch             | properties | houses      | downtown-la | html      |
| jp             | properties | houses      | downtown-la | html      |
| jp.properties  | houses     | downtown    |             | /         |
| ch.properties  | houses     | downtown    |             | /         |
```

Of course, the table has more fields like pageID., and I have other tables to define the content based on the language, page's title, description, keywords, etc.

My goal is to:

1. Have index.php process all uri/url requests into segments.
2. Recognize if the user typed a sub domain/sub-subdomain or not.
3. Pass those values to MySQL, to check if the page exists.
4. Assign the findings to $status (1 for "page found" | 0 for "page not found")
5. If the url/page exists, pass the page's id to $id, so the class can render the
   page (via MySQL)

> ```
> $subdomain = 'properties';
> $sub-subdomain = null;
> $domain = 'domain,com';
> $category = 'houses';
> $subcategory = 'downtown';
> $ext = '/';
>
>
> // url in browser: properties.domain.com/houses/downtown/
> // some php code here to process url (because there's no folders. Only
> root/index.php)    
>
> include('class-page.php');
>    switch ($status) {
>      Case 1:
>         $html =new page::create($id);
>         echo $html;
>         break;
>      case 0:
>         $html =new page::create(404);
>         //php code to rewrite url as: www.domain.com/error/404.html
>      echo $html;
> }
> ```

As you can see, I want to process ALL pages in index.php and make users think they are accessing a page in www.domain.com/category/subcategory/page.html

The problem is, I so not know how to process url/uri in php not how to leave the url intact, without redirecting. I'd like to accomplish this feat with php and VERY little .htaccess (Or none preferably).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method from [DocForge](http://docforge.com/wiki/Clean_URL):

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**index.php**

```
if ($_GET['q']) {
  // Break the request into it's path parts
  $path_parts = explode('/', $_GET['q']);
  $section = $path_parts[0];
}
else {
  $section = 'home';
}

switch ($section) {
  case 'home':
    // Handle requests for the home page
    ...
    break;
  case 'about':
    // Requests to /about
    ...
    break;

 ...
```

One way to get the subdomain in PHP:

```
$subdomain = '';
$domain_parts = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
if (count($domain_parts) > 2) {
    $subdomain = $domain_parts[0];
}
```

Comment: how can I check for subdomains?

Comment: I tried it with subdomains, but it did not work. Do I have to add an .htaccess code to rewrite/route a subdomain? Or is it a must, to register the subdomain in my hosting (godaddy)?

Comment: You don't need to use .htaccess to process subdomains. Your DNS has to be set up for subdomains. That's a completely separate issue.

Comment: I am not sure how to explain this, but I'll try: when typing domain.com/properties/houses/1234-address.html, the url does not change (despite not having any files in that location) and the user is routed to domain.com/index.php. In a similar manner, can I add a code to .htaccess for subdomains (even if they are not registered) to route them to domain.com/index.php (Ej. jp.domain.com/properties/houses/1234-address.html)?

Comment: For the subdomains do you mean redirect? That's a rewrite rule you can google. But your PHP app won't know about that subdomain since the user was redirected first.  If that doesn't answer your question I don't know what else to suggest.  I think all the pieces are here.

Comment: I managed to make sub-domains work. I had to create an `A record` of the sub-domain, pointing to the server (web-host ip). Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I find rewrite rules to be a pain, so I use apache force type and shtml.

Then I use a file named "anything-you-want"

```
<Files anything-you-want>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

I use a 404.shtml error file and the index.shtml page to include the file.

```
<!--#include virtual="/anything-you-want"-->
```

Inside the "anything-you-want" file, I parse the url and based what it is, I display the information.
I'm using it for a search engine api, so one page would act and look like any search engine with an unlimited amount of pages. And I can have my own pages I have written.

index.php - would return the index page or a default search page

about us, contact us, whatever - would return the respective pages for the site.

/tiger/index.php - would use api to return a search on tigers even though there is only three pages.

/airplanes/ - would use api to return a search on airplanes even though there is only three pages.

It's not that hard, just need to step through the logic of what you want it do based on the url.

And you don't need a gadzillion cryptic apache rewrite rules.